# CSS Background Image Alignment of Page with content

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have developed a website in asp.net using master pages.

I have a image with stripes on it as the page background.

I want to use the same image as the background of my head content [Div] in the master page.

I am not well verse with CSS.

How can I can align the stripes of my background with that in website Head content.

Can i make the background of Head content transparent?

or Is there any other way around?

Comment: Please show us your current HTML & CSS in a JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can give your head element the CSS

```
.header_element {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

This will make the back ground transparent, so that the bg picture of your body should be visible.

This most probably much easier as aligning the two backgrounds, since these two backgrounds will align differently with each screen size..

Comment: Changing the background color is transparent is making it white not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

If your background image is on `body` (or is at least wrapping your head) then you can simply make your head div `background:transparent;`

However, if your header div isn't *inside* the element with the background on then you will need to position the background on the head element.

Something like:

```
#header {background-position: 50% 0; }
#otherimageDiv {background-position: 50% 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Done.

I removed my header div outside page div.

and modified the header div background as transparent.